# Daily subsets of Annual Data

Tags: subset, gams-math

I am trying to optimize an energy production process in a year, based on the hourly resolutions. The purchased electricity price from the grid has two different values based on the two times of a day; between 07:00-18:00 the price is 10, between 18:00-07:00 the price is 5.

The time sets are:

```
 P_el     electricityprice              /t7*t18 10, t19*t6 5, ....../  
 t             time                     /t1*t8760/
```

How can I create the P_el automatically, so that I don't need to write different sets by hand until the 8760th hour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do here is make p_el a parameter, not a set. The following should work. (Do check that I got the timing exactly right)

```
set t "time" /t1*t8760/;

parameter hour(t) "hour of the day from 1 to 24";
parameter p_el(t) "electricity price";

hour(t) = mod(ord(t), 24);
p_el(t) = 5;
p_el(t)$(hour(t) >= 7 and hour(t) < 18) = 10;
```

Comment: Dear Martin, thank you so very much, I want to kiss you forever times:) It should be a parameter, yes!